# Run PERL script in BASH

Tags: bash, perl

I use 2 BASH scripts which convert text to file with `.mlf` extension.

**Definition of output in 1. script:**

```
outfile="${mid}_textgrid.mlf"
```

i.e: 1_textgrid.mlf

Script is runned by:

```
bash /var/scripts/textgrid-to-mlf-refference.sh $1
```

**Definition of output in 2. script:**

```
outfile="${mid}_vtt.mlf"
```

i.e: 1_vtt.mlf

Script is runned by:

```
bash /var/scripts/vtt-to-mlf-hypothesis.sh $1
```

`mid`(multimedia identifier) is defined in another script that creates these files. These files are used to compare  using `compare.pl` script(written in PERL). I can run this script using terminal: i.e: `./compare.pl 1_textgrid.mlf 1_vtt.mlf`

Problem is that I want to run this script automatically with BASH script. I tried it in script using: `perl /var/scripts/compare.pl $1_textgrid.mlf $1_vtt.mlf` But it didn't work. Can you give me an example how to run it correctly in this script?

Comment: "But it didn't work" isn't very helpful.  What's the error?

Comment: Try `perl /var/scripts/compare.pl ${1}_textgrid.mlf ${1}_vtt.mlf `

Answer (score -1):

I made new script in BASG to run this "comparing":

```
#!/bin/bash
mid=$1
reff="/home/var/www/vids/$mid/${mid}_textgrid.mlf"
hyp="/home/var/www/vids/$mid/${mid}_vtt.mlf"
out="/home/var/www/vids/$mid/${mid}_wer.txt"

perl /var/scripts/mlf_compare.pl $reff $hyp >> $out
```